# CS0118 without any solution. "Variable used like a type"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, neural-network

Im trying to make my first nerual network and I've followed a few YouTube tutorials. My problem is that the guy Im watching has no error in his code while I do.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class NeuralNetwork : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int[] layers;
    private float[][] neurons;
    private float[][][] weights;

    private System.Random Slumpa;

    public NeuralNetwork()
    {
        this.layers = new int[layers.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < layers.Length; i++)
        {
            this.layers[i] = layers[i];
        }

        Slumpa = new System.Random(System.DateTime.Today.Millisecond);

        InitNeurons();
        InitWeights();
    }
```

neuronsList is contained in the third jagged array float[][][] weights

```
private void InitNeurons()
    {
        List<float[]> neuronsList = new List<float[]>();

        for (int i = 0; i < layers.Length; i++)
        {
            neuronsList.Add(new float[layers[i]]);
        }

        neurons = new neuronsList.ToArray();
    }
```

```
neurons = new neuronList.ToArray();
```

The line above returns the error

I've tried googling this but I've found no solution. I don't know what the problem is so I have not changed anything in the code.

Comment: The problem is the `new` - you just want `neurons = neuronsList.ToArray();`. You're not trying to call a constructor (which is what happens with `new`), you're just trying to call the `ToArray` method.

Comment: Before just following youtube tutorials it could be good to read a book / follow online tutorials before you get into advanced problems. [Get started with unity](https://learn.unity.com/course/getting-started-with-unity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`neuronList` is a variable of type `List<float[]>`, you already instantiated at the beginning of `InitNeurons()` function.

Again while assignment you are trying to create new instance of `neuronsList` **variable** using [`new` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator) instead of assignig directly to `neurons`.

Instead of,

```
neurons = new neuronsList.ToArray();
```

try

```
neurons = neuronsList.ToArray();
```